# Centralizers of elements in free group algebras

Tags: gr.group-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras

Let $A$ be a group algebra of a free group, and $x \in A$. What is the centralizer of $x$? Is there something like *Bergman*'s theorem for free associative algebras?

Comment: I looked through Bergman's paper on centralizers, but didn't see anything specific to free group algebras.  Have you tried emailing Bergman?

Comment: I would expect that the centralizer is equal to the double centralizer. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: What is the double centralizer?  I expect that  the centralizer either has form $F[g,g^{-1}]$ (if $x$ is a linear combination of elements in the  cyclic subgroup generated by $g$ in the free group), or $F[x]$ (if it is not).